# OpenGL cubemap face order & sampling issue

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a renderer based on SDL2 and OpenGL (3.3 core profile), which gives me expected results with regards to transformations and texture(2D)ing.

However, when I'm trying to display a skybox using a cubemap created from [these textures](http://www.humus.name/Textures/Lycksele.zip) (though I've tried others too), there are two steps in the process that no other tutorial or example that I have encountered seems to have to do, and I cannot explain:

1, The top / bottom faces have to be swapped upon uploading, i.e.: the top one is uploaded as `GL_TEXTURE_CUBEMAP_NEGATIVE_Y`, and the bottom one is `GL_TEXTURE_CUBEMAP_POSITIVE_Y`;
2, When sampling the cube map, I have to invert vertex positions along y, but *also* along z;

Without this, I'm getting the following result:

[image]

(N.B. the left-bottom-far vertex was scaled by .8 to clarify that my coordinate system is the right way around)

The image files are named correctly.

The cube is the only draw I'm performing.

If I remove [the indices for] any of the sides, I get the expected results (i.e. no swapping / mirroring there).

I seem to be getting the same results with my integrated and dedicated GPUs.

My OpenGL constants, from a [glLoadGen](https://github.com/zyndor/glloadgen/) ([originally](https://bitbucket.org/alfonse/glloadgen/wiki/Home)) generated header:

```
#define GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X 0x8516
#define GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y 0x8518
#define GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z 0x851A
#define GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X 0x8515
#define GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y 0x8517
#define GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z 0x8519
```

The texture uploading code (much the same as [LearnOpenGL's tutorial](https://learnopengl.com/Advanced-OpenGL/Cubemaps)):

```
GLuint name;
glGenTextures(1, &name);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, name);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));

GLint target = GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X;
for (uint8_t i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
{
  glTexImage2D(target + i, 0, GL_RGB8, width, height, 0, GL_RGB,
    GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixelData[i]));
}
```

Vertex shader:

```
#version 330

precision mediump float;
uniform mat4 uModelViewProjection;
in vec3 aPosition;
out vec3 vTexCoord;

void main()
{
  vec4 position = uModelViewProjection * vec4(aPosition, 1.f);
  gl_Position = position.xyww;
  
  vTexCoord = aPosition;
}
```

Fragment shader:

```
#version 330

precision mediump float;
uniform samplerCube uTexture0;
in vec3 vTexCoord;
out vec4 FragColor;

void main()
{
  FragColor = texture(uTexture0, vTexCoord);
  // using textureCube() yields a compile error asking for #extension  GL_NV_shadow_samplers_cube : enable, but even with that, the issue perists.
}
```

Mesh setup (semi-pseudo-code):

```
//    4----5
//   /|   /|
//  6----7 |
//  | |  | |
//  | 0--|-1
//  |/   |/
//  2----3
VertexType vertices[8] = {
  Vector3(-1.f, -1.f, -1.f) * .8f, // debug coordinate system
  Vector3(1.f, -1.f, -1.f),

  Vector3(-1.f, -1.f, 1.f),
  Vector3(1.f, -1.f, 1.f),

  Vector3(-1.f, 1.f, -1.f),
  Vector3(1.f, 1.f, -1.f),

  Vector3(-1.f, 1.f, 1.f),
  Vector3(1.f, 1.f, 1.f),
};

uint16_t indices[] = {
  4, 0, 5,
  0, 1, 5,

  6, 2, 4,
  2, 0, 4,

  7, 3, 6,
  3, 2, 6,

  5, 1, 7,
  1, 3, 7,

  0, 2, 1,
  2, 3, 1,

  5, 7, 4,
  7, 6, 4,
};

// create buffers & upload data
```

Rendering (pseudo-code):

```
// -clear color & depth buffers;
// -set the model transform to a translation of -10 units along z; 
//   view transform is identity; projection is perspective with .25
//   radians vertical FOV, zNear of .1, zFar of 100.; viewport is full screen
// -set shader program;
// -bind texture (same name, same target as upon uploading);
// -enable backface culling only (no depth test / write);
// -draw the cube
// -glFlush() and swap buffers;
```

What on earth can be causing the two issues described above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is caused by the mapping of the `.str` texture coordinates to the cubemap:

[OpenGL 4.6 API Core Profile Specification, 8.13 Cube Map Texture Selection, page 253](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/glspec46.core.pdf):

> When a cube map texture is sampled, the *(s, t, r)* texture coordinates are treated as a direction vector *(rx, ry, rz)* emanating from the center of a cube. The *q* coordinate is ignored. At texture application time, the interpolated per-fragment direction vector selects one of the cube map face’s two-dimensional images based on the largest magnitude coordinate direction (the major axis direction). If two or more coordinates have the identical magnitude, the implementation may define the rule to disambiguate this situation. The rule must be deterministic and depend only on *(rx, ry, rz)*. The target column in table 8.19 explains how the major axis direction maps to the two-dimensional image of a particular cube map target.
>   Using the *sc*, *tc*, and *ma* determined by the major axis direction as specified in table 8.19, an updated *(s, t)* is calculated as follows:
>
> `s = 1/2 (sc / |m_a| + 1)`
>
> `t = 1/2 (tc / |m_a| + 1)`
>
> ```
> Major Axis Direction|        Target             |sc |tc |ma |
> --------------------+---------------------------+---+---+---+
>        +rx          |TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_X|−rz|−ry| rx|
>        −rx          |TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_X| rz|−ry| rx|
>        +ry          |TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Y| rx| rz| ry|
>        −ry          |TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Y| rx|−rz| ry|
>        +rz          |TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_POSITIVE_Z| rx|−ry| rz|
>        −rz          |TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP_NEGATIVE_Z|−rx|−ry| rz|
> --------------------+---------------------------+---+---+---+
> ```
>
> Table 8.19: Selection of cube map images based on major axis direction of texture
>   coordinates

The rotation can be achieved by either rotating the 6 cubemap images before loading them to the cubemap sampler or by rotating the texture coordinates.

[image]

It cubemap is used as an environment map in a scene and the texture coordinates are get by a direction vector, then it makes sense to rotate the images. If the cubemap is wrapped on a mesh then the texture coordinates can be specified in the right manner.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that's great info. Excuse my lack of speed, but are you basically saying that my Y faces are actually OK, and all my X and Z faces need to be rotated before upload?

While that's plausible / kind of make sense, the libraries (bgfx, DALi) that I have looked at for reference don't seem to need to do that, and I wonder why? If you'd be kind enough to elaborate, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: @zyndor It depends on the source images. The source images can be "rotated" in the right manner and can be loaded as they are. Either the images can be rotated ("photoshop") or they've to be rotated by the application.

Comment: I've downvoted this because the reasoning based on the quoted spec. text is incorrect. The cross figure is misleading. The cubemap images are in an array and all have the same orientation. I'll post another answer below with more details.

Comment: @msc This is just a quote of the specification. Do you mean the specification is wrong?

Comment: @msc *"The cross figure is misleading"* - This is the represents the way you have to put the sides of the cubemap on a piece of paper to fold a cube. Nothing abut my argumentation is wrong.

Comment: @Rabbid76 What I feel is wrong is this statement "This means the side textures have to be rotated before loading them to the cubemap sampler." They do not need to be rotated. Cubemaps work fine with all the x & z images having the same top-down orientation where 'top' is the logical top of the scene, provided you transform the cube coordinates to the cubemap's left-handed system. Rotating the images may be another way of achieving the same end but it makes your cubemaps non-standard.

Comment: @msc *"What I feel is wrong is this statement"* - A feeling does not justify a down vote. They have to be roatated if you read 6 separate tiles from files or if you have a singel bitmap where the tiles are aranged  in a cross (like the image in the texture). If you do not rotate them, then the result is the the image in the question. The rotation can be performed by either rotating the image or the coordinates. Anyway in the documentation is mentioned that the texture coordinates of the cubemap are treated as a 3d vector from the center of the cube.

Comment: @msc Cubemaps were introduced for environment maps, where you do not have texture coordinates. If the coordinates are get from a direction vector then the images have t o be rotated. Cubemaps were introduced for environment maps, not for minecraft cubes. I've mention that in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer's reasoning from the quoted spec. text is wrong.

What is going on is that the quoted text, if you look carefully at the math, requires the cubemap's images to have a *top-down orientation* and be arranged in a left-handed coordinate system with +Y up. That means sky at +Y and if you’re facing +Z, -X should be on your left and +X on your right. This was apparently inherited from Renderman where cube maps first appeared.

The coordinates of the cube you are rendering as the skybox, which will be used to sample the cube map, are in OpenGL's coordinate system which is a right-handed system. These must be transformed to the cubemap's left-handed system before sampling. This is done by simply scaling the Z coord by -1. Failure to do that means the scene will be a mirror image of what it should be. A very common failing in samples I've looked at.

The OPs upside down images are because they had standard OpenGL bottom-up orientation.

If you're using Vulkan, that has a left-handed system but Y is down. So to correctly render the cubemap on Vulkan you still need to transform the skybox cube's coordinates, in this case by rotating them 180° around the X axis. Fail to do that and you'll have upside down images.

Comment: This: "*So to correctly render the cubemap on Vulkan you still need to transform the skybox cube's coordinates, in this case by rotating them 180° around the X axis.*" and this: "*This mean the side textures have to be rotated before loading them to the cubemap sampler.*" ultimately result in the same thing. One transforms the texture coordinates into the space of the cubemap, the other transforms the cubemap's images into the space of the texture coordinate. So I fail to see why the previous answer was incorrect.

Comment: Okay so maybe wrong is the, er, wrong choice of word. If you are creating a cubemap for use on multiple APIs you would have to manipulate the images on loading on one or more of the APIs which I don't think is desirable. Far easier to transform the texture coordinates.

Comment: Plus the original extension spec. says the inside of the cube (i.e. the cubemap) has a left-handed coordinate system. By rotating images you no longer have that and other people stumbling on your cubemap may not know the images have been rotated. Better to be compliant with the spec.

Comment: "This: "So to correctly render the cubemap on Vulkan you still need to transform the skybox cube's coordinates, in this case by rotating them 180° around the X axis." and this: "This mean the side textures have to be rotated before loading them to the cubemap sampler." ultimately result in the same thing." Actually its not. Rotating the coordinates 180° around the x axis also effectively swaps the +y and -y images which is why it enables you to use the exact same cubemap in OpenGL or Vulkan.

Comment: You may consider, that I have changed the reasoning in may answer. Anyway the answer was not wrong. The use case is different to yours. Actually you misuse the cube maps, that are meant for environment mapping.

Comment: Why you think I am misusing cube maps? I'm doing exactly as the Wikipedia reflection mapping article says: "Generally, cube mapping uses the same skybox that is used in outdoor renderings. Cube-mapped reflection is done by determining the vector that the object is being viewed at. This camera ray is reflected about the surface normal of where the camera vector intersects the object. This results in the reflected ray which is then passed to the cube map to get the texel which provides the radiance value used in the lighting calculation. This creates the effect that the object is reflective. "

Comment: [Here](https://registry.khronos.org/KTX/specs/2.0/ktxspec_v2.html#cubemapOrientation) is a good explanation of using skybox coordinates to sample a cubemap to get the same result on OpenGL or Vulkan without any manipulation of the images.

Comment: Both when sampling to decorate a skybox and when sampling to do reflection/environment mapping on an object, the coordinate system of the sample coordinates and that of the cube map must match. In my apps I apply the transforms described in the link in my previous comment to both the skybox coordinates and the reflection vector calculated from the object surface. In the latter case because I'm drawing the object in the API's coordinate system. I strongly recommend against manipulating the images to make the coord systems match as it leads to non-portable cube maps.